# Python - Sort lines in file based on first word?

Tags: python, list, file, sorting

I have a program that prints lists to a file, but I want them to be sorted based on the first word so matching items are next to each other.

For example the file might include:

```
Pizza 5  
Taco 6  
Pizza 4  
Taco 8
```

I want the code to read the file and sort the contents so that the order is based on the first words matching, writing something like this to the file:

```
Pizza 5  
Pizza 4  
Taco 8  
Taco 6
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply read the lines, sort them alphabetically and write them back to the same file:

```
with open("myfile", "r+") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.sort()        
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(lines)
```

This assumes that the file fits in RAM. In case it doesn't, you need to implement some sort of merge sort.

Comment: Minor improvement: Change the last line to `f.writelines(lines)`, which avoids the need to construct a huge string; `writelines` will iterate `lines` and write them out one after another directly (since the file is buffered, smaller writes don't really matter).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `readlines()`, which reads the lines of a file into a list and apply `sorted()` to it.

Comment: `readlines` is redundant/pointless; file objects are iterators of their lines, and `sorted` will already slurp the provided iterator for you.

Comment: It's not exactly redundant. If you want to work with the text afterwards, you don't want to have linebreaks etc. in your lines. This is why it makes sense in some cases to use `readlines()`

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `list`, then loop through the `sorted` list to get the desired result:

```
L = []
with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        L.append(line)
for i in sorted(L):
    print i.strip()
```

Output:

```
Pizza 4
Pizza 5
Taco 6
Taco 8
```

Comment: Constructing the list with your own loop is just wasting time. You could directly do: `L = sorted(f)` and skip the creation of an empty list, the loop of `append`s to make an unsorted `list`, and just have `sorted` slurp and sort all at once.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Does my answer work? YES! Does it deliver the OP's desired result? YES! Is there a better, more efficient way to answer this question? YES! Should my answer be down-voted? NO!